# Can Object Storage GE be used to store images?

Tags: fiware

I am sorry for the lack of research, but I quickly need to know if Object Storage can be used to store images (as in digital photographs)? 
If so, what is the limit in size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object Storage can store any kind of binary file, so yes, you can throw in images. I don't think there's a file size limit, you can assume the limit is of a magnitude of gigabytes.

Answer (score 1):

You can store any kind of data in the Object Store.
The default object size limit in Swift is 5 GB. See http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_large_objects.html.